# In LESS CSS can I get LESS to watch a bunch of files but compile a different file when they change?

Tags: css, less

I have several LESS files that are all imported into one master file (styles.less). My problem at the moment is: when I make a change in one of the child files I have to save style.less to compile it to CSS.

Is there a way in which I can ask less to monitor the child files but only compile the parent?

Cheers,
Ad

Comment: are you using the ruby version? with rails and the more plugin?

Comment: Using the ruby version but not on a ruby site … if that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution for MY problem but it would be great for most.

As I am on a Mac I istalled less.app ( http://incident57.com/less/ ), it uses less.js to compile the less for you. As of a couple of days ago they added a new feature:

> NEW FEATURE: "backwards @import parsing." If you have a file, X, that imports another file, Y, and you make changes to Y, X will now automatically recompile when you save Y (if auto-compile is on). This feature is automatic; there's nothing to turn on or hook up. You'll see "triggered by: X" in the compiler result when it happens.

Turns out it works very well indeed. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: the more plugin seems to handle that also http://github.com/cloudhead/more/blob/master/lib/less/more.rb#L105

Comment: This isn't working as expected I want it to compile the file with `@import` and it's not.

Answer (score 4):

I've hacked a bash script called [lesswatch](https://gist.github.com/1242040) (it doesn't support "backwards @import parsing") that uses [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to listen for file change events and [lessc](http://lesscss.org/#guide) to compile to CSS. I wrote a [short blog post](http://keyes.ie/?p=522) about this today.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fork of less.js that watches file changes and even all files included via @import (like the accepted answer above):

> https://github.com/wvl/less.js

The author of less.js [does not want](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/pull/246#issuecomment-1869806) the --watch option of the old ruby version, so this fork may be your best option for now. Through node.js it can run on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nodejs script and do the same thing.

node less-watch-compiler.js FOLDER_TO_WATCH FOLDER_TO_OUTPUT

https://github.com/jonycheung/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler

It skips watching files with names that starts with underscore or a period.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mac, I currently use less.app from Code Kit
http://incident57.com/less/

It works really well.