# window less compiler that supports "backwards @import parsing

Tags: less

I see that the less.app (on the mac) supports backwards importing

[In LESS CSS can I get LESS to watch a bunch of files but compile a different file when they change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854071/in-less-css-can-i-get-less-to-watch-a-bunch-of-files-but-compile-a-different-fil)

So if I have a global.less that imports an inner less file, it will recompile the global less file, when I change the inner file.

Does anyone know of a way to do this using the less.js in browser compiler? Or is that impossible?

Or probably even better, a windows based compiler that would do this or be able to watch the folder but just compile the global file when any of the folders change.

So far I've tried winless, the less parser and simpless and neither of these will do this. Even if it comiled all the less files to when anything changes in the folder I'd be happy.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Just to let people know that the people behihd both Simpless and the Less Parser have let me know that this is something they intend to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for automatic backwards @import compiling has been added to WinLess in version 1.1.0.