# Weird error when importing Bootstrap as LESS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

OK, so what I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward :

- I renamed my pre-customized Bootstrap CSS file to a `.less` extension (as the documentation seems to suggest)
- I'm `@import`ing this `less` file at the beginning of another less file (`styles.less`)
- My `styles.less` file is properly linked in the head of my HTML page and rendered using JavaScript.

However, it keeps reporting an error I simply CANNOT see.

The **exact** error it shows (at the top of the page) :

```
missing opening `{`
in bootstrap.less on line 580, column 8:

579 
580
```

And here's my **bootstrap.less** : https://gist.github.com/drkameleon/5562962#file-bootstrap-less

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:** Even more weird : when compiling my `styles.less` files, from the terminal, using `lessc`, it compiles just fine... :S

Comment: I compiled it with http://www.freeformatter.com/less-compiler.html and it gave no errors...

Comment: what are you using to compile it when you get the error?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester That's possible. Please, have a look at my last edit in the original post... Is is possible that the JS compiler is buggy?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon That is probably it, yes.

Comment: @soulcheck I'm using the JS compiler : `<script src="path/to/the/compiler/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Well, if that is the case, then I guess I'll have to precompile it locally and update the version being used in the page. (not the greatest thing for development purposes though... arghh! :S)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I don't get any error with less 1.3.3. can you post the importing stylesheet and your less version?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I'm not using LESS but with SASS you can add the --watch option for the commandline tool. It watches for file changes and compiles them immediately. Great for development. Less has no native support for that I believe. But you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854071/in-less-css-can-i-get-less-to-watch-a-bunch-of-files-but-compile-a-different-fil

Comment: To me it gets properly compiled in all LESS.js versions newer than 1.2.0, and in older ones there are other errors, but it seems strange, so it might be something with the importing.

Comment: @MartinTurjak I'm using v. `1.3.3`.

Comment: Mhm, It seems to compile fine in 1.3.3 for me and for @soulcheck, have you tried compiling just the bootstrap.less, without the other file? So maybe you could try giving us all you have, so we can try reproducing the error. I have no other idea.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Give me a second, and I'll try it. Seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: @MartinTurjak Pretty stupid of me, yup : I was missing the correct path for the `.less` being imported. (OK, and maybe I mixed the order in which some of my older existing `.css` files were being loaded, so that kept giving me the wrong impression). So : no problem with the compiler (and that's **good news**!).

Comment: Glad we could nudge you in the right direction =)

Comment: @MartinTurjak Well, it helps at times... You know it's usually called the "Programmer's temporary... blindness"... lol. Thanks again! ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon please close/delete the question, as after all it's too localized :)

Comment: I just voted for it to close. :)