# Managing Humongous LESS files

Tags: less

I went from having one unmaintainable LESS file to having the following in style.less:

```
@import "site/auth.less";
@import "site/suggestions.less";
@import "site/header+footer.less";
@import "site/home.less";
@import "site/info.less";
@import "site/profile.less";
```

So, `style.less` is responsible only for compiling all of the separate less files together into a single CSS file for my app.

But in each of these less files, I have the following line at the top:

```
 @import "master.less";
```

Which contains all of the common variables, colors, fonts, etc that each of the other less files depend on.

This is working, but I have two problems:

1. Every time I make a change to `site/info.less`, I have to save in both that file, and `style.less`, to trigger the recompile.
2. My compiled CSS contains the contents of `master.less` 6 times.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding #2

LESS 1.5 now allows reference imports, like so:

```
@import (reference) "master.less";
```

This will only import a file for reference purposes and not compile to css. So you can put this at the top of each of your separate files and not have to have 6 versions show up in your css.

Of course, if you do actually want it compiling to css at least once for your `style.less`, then you would actually want to include it normally at the top of that file. But if it is in fact just variables and things to reference, then that is not needed.

### Regarding #1

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854071/in-less-css-can-i-get-less-to-watch-a-bunch-of-files-but-compile-a-different-fil/3855762#3855762) may have some solutions for you.

Comment: Is this supported in Visual Studio via Web Essentials?

Comment: @SB2055: I don't know for sure, as that all depends on what version of LESS they are using. LESS 1.5 is the newest release, and from the [current change log of Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog), it looks like they are only up to 1.4.2 (revision 2.9; revisions 3.0, 3.1 don't mention any further upgrade). It will probably be available soon.